# How to show preview of entered values in previous steps in webform with multiple steps

Tags: webforms, forms

I am configuring a "**Webform**". In my webform field components, I am using "**page break**" in order to create Multiple step forms.

But I like to show the entered value in previous steps in current step.

for example, if user is in step 2, I want to print entered value of step 1 bellow the form.
or if user is in step 3, I like to print the entered value of step 2 and step 1 bellow the form.

is there any module to run this scenario? or I have to program a custom module?

Please guide me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Webform Bonus Pack](https://drupal.org/project/webform_bonus) module, it have the option to preview webform fields before submission.

> which allows you to add a summary component directly to your form in
>   the same way you would add a textfield or any other component type.
>   Install that module and add a summary field to your form, selecting
>   which fields you would like to include in the summary. If you would
>   like it on its own page, make sure to add a pagebreak component first.

also take a look at this https://drupal.org/node/435232

Comment: Dear Bala, I have another question, IF I use your mentioned module, can I have this summary in every step of form (I mean every page) or I can have it only in end step (page)?

Comment: @Mehrdad201 not sure and I'm not using this module before, have a try and but I think you can show for each step.

Comment: Ok, I will try it asap

Comment: I tested it. It works fine. In every page I can have a summary from selected fields. Thanks a lot Bala.